# Atualizar ListView após retorno com PopAsync em Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, xamarin-forms

Como atualizar a `ListView` após voltar para a `View` usando o `PopAsync` ?
Preciso que a `ListView` carregue os items dela após a View de Inserção de Endereços gravar um novo endereço.

**OBS:** O `PushAsync` ou `PushModalAsync` retornam para a `View` corretamente, porém errado para o que preciso.

InserirEnderecoViewModel:

```
    if (Api.APICliente.InserirEndereco(objEnd) == 0)
    {
         if (alteracao == false)
         {
             await Page.DisplayAlert("Mensagem", "Endereço inserido com sucesso!", "OK");
         }
         else
             await Page.DisplayAlert("Mensagem", "Endereço alterado com sucesso!", "OK");
    }
    else
        await Page.DisplayAlert("Alerta", "Não foi possível inserir os dados!", "OK");

// Aqui retorna para a View de MeusEndereços onde contem a ListView que irá carregar os endereços cadastrados.
await Page.Navigation.PopAsync();
```

Comment: Pelo título/formulação da pergunta você já está conseguindo passar os dados, já está conseguindo? Falta somente atualizar a `Listview`? Como está o código da `Listview`a ser preenchida?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na sua View de MeusEndereços

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    BindingContext = new suaViewModel();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Para preencher um ListView no Xamarin.Forms é sempre recomendado utilizar um ObservableCollection pois ela notifica qualquer mudança da coleção(insert,delete,update).
Bom com uma ObservableColection no ItemSource da ListView usando o padrão MVVM sua Page da ListView tem um Evento chamado Appearing Você Pode chamar o método do seu viewModel que preencher os dados da listview neste evento.
Exemplo :

```
    public partial class Page : ContentPage
    {
        private PageViewModel vm;
        public Page()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            vm = new PageViewModel(this.Navigation);
            this.BindingContext = vm;
            this.Appearing += TennisClubMessagePage_Appearing;
        }

        private void TennisClubMessagePage_Appearing(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            vm.LoadDataAsync();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Sobrescreva o método  OnAppearing da sua view.

Por exemplo:

```
 protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        lstParceiro.SelectedItem = null;
        AtualizarLista();
    }
```

Nesse caso eu deleguei para um método (AtualizarLista) a tarefa de atualizar o ItemsSource da minha lista.

Answer (score 0):

Crie um `event handler` no `viewmodel`, e outro na `view`,
quando for chamar o form, seja modal ou não.

No `form` que for chamar o `form modal`, faça a seguinte chamada:

```
var modalform = new seumodalform();
modalform.seuviewhandler += async(O,e)=>{ o valr que voce quer atualizar = O;}
```

No construtor da `view` é só definir:

```
seuVM.seuVMHandler = seuViewHandler;

//E na rotina que fechar o view, se for realizado via mvvm
seuVMhandler?.invoke(objeto, args);

//Se for feito via codebehind da view, basta fazer o mesmo invoke
seuViewhandler?.invoke(objeto, args);
```